# Import Facebook posts and send them via message or WhatsApp

Tags: facebook, import, save, whatsapp, forward

We have this great group on Facebook where people post stuff about speed-controls or if some accident happened in order to make your traveling much easier and faster.

We would love to import those facebook commands, save them and automatically push them to all registered phone numbers via Whatsapp (messaging). This can be done using the whatsapp webclient or manually. As long as the posts are  saved somewhere, I can forward them. Does anybody perhaps know the best way to do this?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Example code and information for group feeds: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed

You need to use a user token of someone who is in the group, with the `user_groups` permission. Keep in mind that you will not get that permission approved by Facebook, so you can only use it as user with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester):

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_groups

How you save those group entries is totally up to you, it´s definitely to broad to answer in here. Choose a database and learn how to use it with books, tutorials, docs, ... Famous ones are MySQL or MongoDB.